# Can't connect to Hashicorp Vault in Docker container with AWS authentication- x509 certificate error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, hashicorp-vault

I have a Docker container that contains a service that needs to connect to Vault to retrieve secrets to run the service.  My container is running Linux CentOS

In my entrypoint.sh script that runs in my Docker container I attempt to retrieve Vault secrets using the Vault CLI, then authenticate using AWS authentication.

Relevant code from Dockerfile:

```
# Set environment variables
ENV VAULT_URL=https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/1.0.1/vault_1.0.1_linux_amd64.zip
ENV VAULT_ADDR=MY_VAULT_ADDR_REMOVED

# Install Vault CLI for managing secrets
RUN yum install unzip -y
RUN curl -fSL "$VAULT_URL" -o /bin/vault.zip
RUN unzip /bin/vault.zip -d /bin
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Relevant code from entrypoint.sh

```
# Login with Vault and get secrets

vault login -namespace $VAULT_NAMESPACE -method=aws role=my_role aws_access_key_id=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID aws_secret_access_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY aws_security_token=$AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN
vault read -namespace $VAULT_NAMESPACE some_kv
```

Note:
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,  and $AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN are passed in at runtime as environment variables to the Docker container.

When I run the command:

```
vault login -namespace $VAULT_NAMESPACE -method=aws role=my_role aws_access_key_id=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID aws_secret_access_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY aws_security_token=$AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN
```

I receive the following error

```
Error authenticating: Put https://VAULT_URL/v1/auth/aws/login: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have verified that I can make the same `vault login` call from my local machine with the AWS credentials successfully.

**It's clear to me that this is a certificate issue, but I'm not sure what steps I need to take to resolve it.**

*Things I have tried:*

Updated the Dockerfile like this, where the vault-cert.cer is a file I downloaded from my browser using the certificate export wizard

```
# Certificates
COPY src/vault-cert.cer $WSO2IS_HOME/vault-cert.cer
RUN yum install ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-trust force-enable
RUN cp vault-cert.cer /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
RUN update-ca-trust extract
```

I was hoping adding the .cer file to the filesystem would allow the Docker container to trust the URL I am authenticating against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command solved my issue:

`# Configure Trust for Vault Certificate
RUN openssl s_client -connect $VAULT_HOST:443 < /dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' >> /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`